parsing time in different numbers of time symbols
I have a vector of dates and times
tm <- c("20231130 162900", "20231009 75400", "20240216 3100", "20230725 0")

I convert it to time format
library(tidyverse)
strsplit(tm, " ") |>
  map_chr(\(x)  paste(x[1], stringr::str_pad(x[2], 6, "left", "0"))) |>
  lubridate::ymd_hms()

result
[1] "2023-11-30 16:29:00 UTC" "2023-10-09 07:54:00 UTC" "2024-02-16 00:31:00 UTC" "2023-07-25 00:00:00 UTC"

What are some shorter and more readable options to do this conversion?

We could Vectorize sub and replace with strrep.
> Vectorize(sub,,,FALSE)('\\s', strrep('0', 15L - nchar(tm)), tm) |> 
+   strptime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S', tz='UTC')
[1] "2023-11-30 16:29:00 UTC" "2023-10-09 07:54:00 UTC"
[3] "2024-02-16 00:31:00 UTC" "2023-07-25 00:00:00 UTC"


Not sure about readability, but you can pass padding operation as a function to str_replace() and skip split & map:
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)

tm <- c("20231130 162900", "20231009 75400", "20240216 3100", "20230725 0")
tm |> 
  str_replace("\\d+$", \(time_) str_pad(time_, 6, "left", "0")) |> 
  ymd_hms()
#> [1] "2023-11-30 16:29:00 UTC" "2023-10-09 07:54:00 UTC"
#> [3] "2024-02-16 00:31:00 UTC" "2023-07-25 00:00:00 UTC"

Created on 2024-04-25 with reprex v2.1.0

The str_replace could be written as str_replace("\\d+$", ~ str_pad(.x, 6, "left", "0")) 
